# How many permutations of numbers $(1,2,3, .., n)$ are there in which at least $2$ elements are in their original place?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, inclusion-exclusion

How many permutations of numbers $$(1,2,3, .., n)$$ are there in which at least $2$ elements are in their original place?

My idea for solving:
$n! - |\text{no element stands in its original place}| - |\text{exactly one element is in its original place}|$

Is it correct?

Comment: The number of derangement does not have a known formula. I think the best way is to use inclusion-exclusion, "fix two numbers" - "fix three numbers" + "fix four numbers" .etc will give you ${n\choose 2}(n-2)!-{n\choose 3}(n-3)!+{n\choose 4}(n-4)!- ...$

Comment: Yes, that would be a good approach, but I think you've misstated the last part.  Don't you mean "exactly one element is in its original place?"

Comment: @saulspatz, yes. Thank you.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rencontres_numbers

Comment: Yes but be careful! The case in which none of the elements stands in its original place is really non trivial(a similar permutation is called derangement): I suggest you a recursive approach. Once you solved this the second cardinality should be easy.

Comment: The end result is that it is going to be $n! - !n - n\cdot !(n-1)$ where $!k$ is the "subfactorial" counting the number of [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement), permutations on $k$ elements with no fixed positions, the most common formulas for which involve either inclusion-exclusion or division by $e$ and floor functions.  Further information is available in the link provided and contrary to what @cr001 there *is* a very well known formula for.

Answer (score 2):

We split the problem into subproblems.

How many exist with exactly one element in the same place?

Select one element to remain in the same place.
For each selection, we find the [derangement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) of the remaining (n-1) elements. . This tells us that there are $\frac{(n-1)!}{e}$ (rounded to the nearest integer so written $\left\lfloor \frac{(n-1)!}{e} +0.5 \right  \rfloor$ ) ways to permutate n-1 elements so none are in the same place. This gives us $n \times \left\lfloor \frac{(n-1)!}{e} +0.5 \right  \rfloor$ as we multiply by n for all the choices of fixed elements.

How many exist elements with none in the same place?

Similarly we get $\left\lfloor \frac{(n)!}{e} +0.5\right\rfloor$.

So the final answer is $n! - \left\lfloor \frac{(n)!}{e} +0.5\right\rfloor - n \times \left\lfloor \frac{(n-1)!}{e} +0.5\right\rfloor $

Comment: As for the rounding to nearest integer, that is best to be explicitly phased in the expression itself using floor functions.  $\left\lfloor k + \frac{1}{2}\right\rfloor$ (*typeset as `$\left\lfloor k + \frac{1}{2}\right\rfloor$`*) gives the integer closest to $k$ (*rounding down in the case of $0.5$, but that is irrelevant here since $k!/e$ is always irrational*)

Answer (score 1):

We first compute the number of permutations with zero or one elements in
their original place. Using combinatorial classes we have the following
class $\mathcal{P}$  of permutations with fixed points marked:

$$\def\textsc#1{\dosc#1\csod}
\def\dosc#1#2\csod{{\rm #1{\small #2}}}
\mathcal{P} = \textsc{SET}(
\mathcal{U} \times \textsc{CYC}_{=1}(\mathcal{Z}) +
\textsc{CYC}_{=2}(\mathcal{Z})  +
\textsc{CYC}_{=3}(\mathcal{Z})  + \cdots).$$

This gives the EGF

$$G(z, u) = \exp\left(uz+\frac{z^2}{2}
+ \frac{z^3}{3}
+ \frac{z^4}{4}
+ \cdots \right)
\\ = \exp\left(\log\frac{1}{1-z} + (u-1)z\right)
= \frac{1}{1-z} \exp\left((u-1)z\right)
\\ = \frac{1}{1-z} \exp\left(-z\right)
\exp\left(uz\right).$$

We have for the desired statistic

$$n! [z^n] ([u^0] + [u^1]) G(z, u)
= n! [z^n] \frac{1}{1-z} \exp(-z) (1 + z).$$

Extracting the coefficients we find

$$n! \times
\left( \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}
+ \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!} \right).$$

This is

$$2 n! \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}
- (-1)^n.$$

The desired answer is thus

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
n! + (-1)^n - 2n! \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}.}$$

which is

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
n! + (-1)^n - 2 \times !n.}$$

This gives the sequence

$$0, 1, 1, 7, 31, 191, 1331, 10655, 95887, 958879, \ldots$$

which is [OEIS A155521](https://oeis.org/A155521), where these data are
confirmed.